# why "new" keyword is not contextual keyword?

Tags: c#, keywords

Based on: [C# Keywords](http://marker.to/Ef9nmf)

> **Keywords** are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler.

and Based on: [Contextual Keywords](http://marker.to/HGVCnu)

> A **contextual keyword** is used to provide a specific meaning in the code, but it is not a reserved word in C#.

For Keyword **new**  we have multiple situation for use it, for example:

```
//One situation for create an instance of class:
StringBuilder sr=new StringBuilder();

//Another situation for method hiding in polymorphism subject of OOP:
public new void Foo()
{
   //Some Code
}
```

As you can see **new** keyword has Several meaning Depending on where it's used, then in my openion **new** must considered as Contextual Keyword and not keyword!

then, the Definition of Contextual keyword is wrong? or considering **new** as whole keyword? and why?

Comment: So it is var or new? You seem confused.

Comment: @Euphoric Thanks for the reminder , I was wrong! :) the post edited

Comment: See also Eric Lippert's post on the topic: [Reserved and contextual keywords](http://ericlippert.com/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is not how many meanings it has, but whether or not it's reserved.

When Microsoft adds new features to C#, it sometimes need to add new keywords. This can compromise backward compatibility, since it invalidates old code that declares identifiers with the same name. To prevent this, Microsoft makes these new keywords contextual - they only serve as keywords when placed in specific places, places where you can't normally put identifiers.

So - `async` is a contextual keyword because older code might have declared a variable named `async`.

`new` was there from day one, so it doesn't have this problem - if your code declared a variable named `new` it wouldn't work even in the first version of C#. Therefore, there is no backwards compatibility issue here and `new` can be a regular keyword.

Comment: +1 for your excellent explanation, i don't have enough reputation for vote up, good and important point but i Wonder why this important issue has not been mentioned in MSDN.

Comment: ["C# 1.0 had contextual keywords get set value add remove for properties, indexers and events..."](http://marker.to/5Bk8zh) We had another version before C# 1.0 !?

Comment: We had contextual keywords in C# 1.0 too.

Comment: There goes my theory...

Comment: I 'm satisfied with your answer , but now, I have another question. why c# 1.0 must have Contextual keywords? because there was no backwards compatibility issue at that time!

Comment: @programmer1: Read the article linked in my comment on your question.

Comment: @Brian Thanks, I read it and first question solved but now, another question is raised, **"why c# 1.0 must have Contextual keywords?"**, in that article, i can't find any answer for this question.

Comment: Actually, that article does answer that question: "Because we could easily get away with making them contextual keywords, and it seemed likely that real people would want to name variables or methods things like get, set, value, add or remove. So we left them unreserved as a courtesy."